# How to use Sencha app watch with custom app?

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs5

I have a web application whose front is on Extjs, Currently I am building a theme so I wanted use **Sencha app watch** command to get the live update as and when I make changes in scss files. But I am getting 404 error for fashion.js and sass-compiler.js file. Please let me know how can I use it to see live updates.
below are the console errors I see in the developer tool.

bootstrap.js:1595 GET http://localhost:8080/~cmd/extensions/sencha-fashion/fashion/fashion.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

bootstrap.js:1595 GET http://localhost:8080/~cmd/extensions/sencha-fashion/sass-compiler.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

My application is hosted on tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify a static resource location to the workspace

Comment: `Sencha app watch` work with sencha cmd if you have created your application sencha cmd then it will work. otherwise you will get error and you have resolved all the error.